# How to query an item in a nested relationship?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Phoenix Framework 1.0.2

I have a `user_post_path()` because I am making `Users` `has_many` `Posts`.

in my Posts controller I do:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id, "user_id" => user_id}) do
    post = Post |> Repo.get!(id)
    user = User |> Repo.get!(user_id) 
    render(conn, :index, post: post, user: user)
end
```

in my `post/show.html` I have:

```
<%= link "Edit", to: user_post_path(@conn, :edit, @user, @post) %>
```

First question, is it inefficient to write 2 queries? ie.
`Repo.get!(id)` and `Repo.get!(user_id)`

Or is it more efficient to write something like this:

`user_with_post = User |> Repo.get!(user_id) |> Repo.preload [:posts] |> #now do something to get posts.id = 5 for example`

I assume it is more efficient to write one query, (please correct me if I'm wrong!), which leads  me to my second question.

Once I preload posts, I can't simply `Repo.get(post_id)` because I get "not a queryable" error. What is the proper way to filter the posts of a user so that I only get the users details with the specific post id/ids I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods (calling `Repo.get!` twice and using `Repo.preload`) will make two queries. You can verify this by looking in your phoenix console when calling the show action.

However if there is a has many association but you only want one of the users posts, I would write:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id, "user_id" => user_id}) do
    user = User |> Repo.get!(user_id) 
    post = assoc(user, :posts) |> Repo.get!(post_id)
    render(conn, :index, post: post, user: user)
end
```

Using [assoc/2](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Model.html#assoc/2) you can ensure that the post belongs to the user - which is what I believe you are trying to do.